# PHP populate drop box with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script which fetches options from a script php to populate a drop down list on the main page.

Here's the javascript

```
   <script>
   //# this script uses jquery and ajax it is used to set the values in
           $(document).ready(function(){   
                //# the time field whenever a day is selected. 
                $("#day").change(function() {   

                      var day=$("#day").val();
                      var doctor=$("#doctor").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"time.php",
                          data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor,
                          dataType : 'json'
                          success: function(data) {
                                //# $("#time").html(data);
                                var option = '';
                                $.each(data.d, function(index, value) {
                                     option += '<option>' + value.timing + '</option>';
                                });
                                $('#timing').html(option);
                             }
                       });
                  });
             });
   </script>
```

Here's the php script which gets data from a database.

```
  <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","clinic","myclinic","myclinic");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $doctor = $_POST['doctor'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE doctor='" .$doctor."'AND day='" .$day. "'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    //$res = array();

    echo "<select name='timing' id='timing'>";

    //Initialize the variable which passes over the array key values
    $i = 0;                                 

    //Fetches an associative array of the row
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Fetches an array of keys for the row.    
    $index = array_keys($row);             

    while($row[$index[$i]] != NULL)
    {
        if($row[$index[$i]] == 1) {             
            //array_push($res, $index[$i]);
            json_encode($index[$i]);

            echo "<option value='"  . $index[$i]."'>" . $index[$i] . "</option>";
        }
        $i++;
    }       

    echo json_encode($res);

    echo "</select>";

  ?>
```

It's not working. I get an error from console saying missing '}' in javasrcipt on line

```
  $("#day").change(function(){
```

I can't seem to find an error either.

Comment: Try adding a comma after the dataType option in your code and your jquery code should be fine.

Comment: mysql injection here i come...

Comment: I'll worry about sqlinjections after I get this working :)

Comment: Thanks ! It's still not populating the list on my page though.
Can you look at my php script to see what's wrong?

Comment: Code it right at the first attempt, do not postpone it. This isn't how things are done. If you're learning, try to learn good practices ASAP. If you are an expert and purposely postponed error/trouble checking, shame on you.

Comment: Yes I am a newbie and you're right I'll correct this

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a comma on the line above the one triggering the error :

```
dataType : 'json',
```

Comment: Ahh my bad. It's still not populating the list. Can you take a look at my code and see whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have a comma on the line above it...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where is problem, because you mixed things together. On Javascript side you expect JSON but on PHP side you generate HTML.

Use JSON for sending data between server and browser. Ensure that you actually generate valid JSON and only JSON.

This line does nothing (function returns value, but not modifies it)

```
json_encode($index[$i]);
```

This line does not make sense - variable $res is not initialized;

```
echo json_encode($res);
```